# MySQL: WHERE parameter prevents all items from showing in result

Tags: mysql, where-clause

First of all, I am sure I haven't formulated my question correctly but I am not sure how to, so please feel free to edit it. I will try to explain the problem below:

I have a database of music tracks. One table contains the trackID, track name, bpm, length, etc. Another table contains all musical styles associated with the track (a track can have one or more styles), in two columns:

```
trackID – styleID
2830 – 66
2830 – 24
2829 – 66
2828 – 66
2828 – 24
```

When I display all tracks, I concatenate the styles for each track using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

This works as expected until I filter the results by style using `WHERE`. When I do this, if a track has more than one style, only one style is displayed.

I think the styleID declared in the condition prevents the `SELECT` query from retrieving all styles for this track. But I don't know how to fix this. Here is my full query:

```
SELECT vt.trackID, vt.vinylID, vt.trackArtist, vt.side, vt.trackTitle, vt.notes, vt.bpm, vt.keyID, vk.keyName, vt.length, vd.Artist, vd.Title, vd.Image, vk.Camelot, vk.Traktor, GROUP_CONCAT(vts.styleID SEPARATOR ',') AS 'styleIDs', GROUP_CONCAT(vs.styleName SEPARATOR ',') AS 'styleNames'
FROM vinyl_tracks vt
INNER JOIN vinyl_data vd ON vt.vinylID = vd.vinylID
LEFT JOIN vinyl_keys vk ON vt.keyID = vk.keyID
LEFT JOIN vinyl_tracks_styles vts ON vt.trackID = vts.trackID
INNER JOIN vinyl_styles vs ON vts.styleID = vs.styleID
WHERE vts.styleID = 66 AND vt.notes NOT LIKE '%reject%'
GROUP BY vt.trackID
ORDER BY vt.trackID DESC LIMIT 0, 50;
```

I hope you can help me figure out how to solve this issue.

EDIT: Adding two screenshots for illustration. The first one has the 'style' filter on, the second one has no filter applied.

[image: Style filter ON]
[image: Style filter OFF]

Comment: What is your desired results? You want to retain any track and ALL of its styles, if it has the style 66?

Comment: @JNevill, I want to see (display) all the styles for all tracks that fall into the selected style. Some tracks will only have the selected style, others will have two styles.

Comment: Not `WHERE vts.styleID = 66` but `HAVING SUM(vts.styleID = 66)`

Comment: @Akina, where exactly do I put this? If I put it after the `WHERE` clause, e.g. `WHERE vt.notes NOT LIKE '%reject%' HAVING SUM (vts.styleID = 66)`, PhpMyAdmin tells me "Unexpected ordering of clauses (near HAVING)".

Comment: o_O HAVING must be placed after GROUP BY.

Comment: @Akina, thank you! It works! At first I placed it after GROUP BY but left a space between `SUM` and the opening bracket, and the query threw an error, which I didn't read carefully.

Comment: @Akina, please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.